# Why is my data member empty even after construction?

Tags: c++

I have included both my definition of the Question class and its implementation, the first is a header file and the second a cpp file.

I put comments in to show where the problem is.  For some reason under the constructor I can cout the questionText just fine but when I try to do this under the getQuestionText function it just outputs an empty string?  Any help would be most appreciated!! Thanks!

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#ifndef QUESTION_H
#define QUESTION_H

class Question{
public:
    Question(int thePointValue, int theChapterNumber, \
        string theQuestionText);
    int getPointValue() const;
    int getChapterNumber() const;
    string getQuestionText() const;
    virtual void writeQuestion(ostream& outfile) const;
    virtual void writeKey(ostream& outfile) const;

private:
    int pointValue;
    int chapterNumber;
    string questionText;

    void writePointValue(ostream& outfile) const;
};




#endif





#include "Question.h"

Question::Question(int thePointValue, int theChapterNumber, \
        string theQuestionText)
{
    pointValue = thePointValue;
    chapterNumber = theChapterNumber;
    questionText = theQuestionText;

        //HERE THIS WORKS PERFECTLY
        cout << questionText << endl;
}

int Question::getPointValue() const
{
    return pointValue;
}

int Question::getChapterNumber() const
{
    return chapterNumber;
}

string Question::getQuestionText() const
{
        //THIS IS THE PROBLEM. HERE IT OUPUTS AN EMPTY STRING NO MATTER WHAT!
        cout << questionText << endl;
    return questionText;
}

void Question::writeQuestion(ostream& outfile) const
{
    writePointValue(outfile);
    outfile << questionText << endl;
}

void Question::writeKey(ostream& outfile) const
{
    writePointValue(outfile);
    outfile << endl;
}

void Question::writePointValue(ostream& outfile) const
{
    string pt_noun;

    if (pointValue == 1)
        pt_noun = "point";
    else
        pt_noun = "points";

    outfile << "(" << pointValue << " " << pt_noun << ") ";
}

vector<Question *> QuestionsList(string filename, int min, int max)
{
vector<Question *> QuestionList;

string line;
vector<string> text;
ifstream in_file;
in_file.open(filename.c_str());
while (getline(in_file, line))
{
    text.push_back(line);
}

string type;
for(int i = 0; i < text.size(); i ++)
{
    int num = text[i].find('@');
    type = text[i].substr(0, num);
    if (type == "multiple")
    {
        MultipleChoiceQuestion myq = matchup(text[i]);
        MultipleChoiceQuestion* myptr = &myq;
        if (myq.getChapterNumber() >= min && myq.getChapterNumber() <= max)
        {
            QuestionList.push_back(myptr);
        }
    }
    if (type == "short")
    {
        ShortAnswerQuestion myq = SAmatchup(text[i]);
        ShortAnswerQuestion* myptr = &myq;
        if (myq.getChapterNumber() >= min && myq.getChapterNumber() <= max)
        {
            QuestionList.push_back(myptr);
        }
    }
    if (type == "long")
    {
        LongAnswerQuestion myq = LAmatchup(text[i]);
        LongAnswerQuestion* myptr = &myq;
        if (myq.getChapterNumber() >= min && myq.getChapterNumber() <= max)
        {
            QuestionList.push_back(myptr);
        }
    }
    if (type == "code")
    {
        CodeQuestion myq = CODEmatchup(text[i]);
        CodeQuestion* myptr = &myq;
        if (myq.getChapterNumber() >= min && myq.getChapterNumber() <= max)
        {
            QuestionList.push_back(myptr);
        }
    }
    cout << QuestionList[QuestionList.size()-1]->getQuestionText() << endl;
}
for (int i = 0; i < QuestionList.size(); i ++)
{
    int numm = QuestionList.size();
    cout << QuestionList[numm-1]->getQuestionText() << endl;
}
return QuestionList;
```

}

then when i call this in main the code breaks

```
vector<Question *> list = QuestionsList(pool_filename, min_chapter, max_chapter);
cout << list[0]->getQuestionText() << endl;
```

Comment: You are initializing something to string at some point in your main right?

Comment: Show how the `Question` object is initialized at the point it's being used. You are calling the constructor that takes arguments, not a the default (empty) one, right?

Comment: May we see a [sscce](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: This program [compiles and executes correctly](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=82cb72807cc7e1b9c1d9bf63460224cf-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba).

Comment: In the main `Question q(1, 1, "TestString"); q.getQuestionText();` prints `TestString TestString`.

Comment: The program has no problem compiling the problem is when i am in the main function and call:                                        vector<Question *> list = QuestionsList(pool_filename, min_chapter, max_chapter);   cout << list[0]->getQuestionText() << endl;   you get an error on the cout part and it crashes

Comment: What is a `QuestionsList`? Please produce ALL the relevant code.

Comment: Are you sure you need a vector of pointers, and not just actual objects? Vectors of raw pointers always make me cringe.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring, multiple times in your code, local objects and storing their pointer into the `QuestionList` vector (returned by the function) which, at the end of the function block, will contains [*dangling pointers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

```
MultipleChoiceQuestion myq = matchup(text[i]); // < local object
MultipleChoiceQuestion* myptr = &myq; // < pointer to local object

QuestionList.push_back(myptr); // < push back into vector
```

At this point you can either use [*dynamic memory allocation*](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/) (I suggest you not to do that unless you are absolutely forced, and even in that case use one of the [*smart pointers*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one) provided by the standard library) or store the objects directly inside the vector.